# Error with to_proto(caffe-master/python/caffe/net_spec.py)-- 'LayerParameter' object has no attribute 'num_output'

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, resnet

I'm trying to create the train.protxt of resnet with pycaffe and I got this error:

> File "/data/hjy1312/Downloads/caffe-master/python/caffe/net_spec.py", line 140, in _to_proto
>       inp._to_proto(layers, names, autonames)
>   File "/data/hjy1312/Downloads/caffe-master/python/caffe/net_spec.py", line 97, in _to_proto
>       return self.fn._to_proto(layers, names, autonames)
>     File "/data/hjy1312/Downloads/caffe-master/python/caffe/net_spec.py", line 162, in _to_proto
>       assign_proto(layer, k, v)
>     File "/data/hjy1312/Downloads/caffe-master/python/caffe/net_spec.py", line 64, in assign_proto
>       is_repeated_field = hasattr(getattr(proto, name), 'extend')
>   AttributeError: 'LayerParameter' object has no attribute 'num_output'

after setting the breakpoint and running my code,i found the wrong with my code is this line:

```
from caffe import layers as L, params as P, to_proto  
return to_proto(acc, loss)
```

But I don't know what’s wrong with to_proto,could anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, you get the error when executing `to_protot()` function, but the error is not in the function itself, but rather in the inputs **you** provide.
Look at the error message you got

> ```
> AttributeError: 'LayerParameter' object has no attribute 'num_output'
> ```

As one can understand from the error message, the net spec you provided has a layer (maybe more than one) that has `num_output` attribute for the layer itself (instead of an attribute to the layer's parameters).

In order to fix this error you need to inspect the code defining the layers and see that `num_output` is assigned to the layer params and not to the layer directly.

Comment: Thank you very much！I think I have known what‘s wrong with my code.I just mistake convolution for Convolution.It's this line:                                     conv = L.Convolution(bottom, kernel_size = kernelsize, stride = stride,